# Display Database Items on php

Tags: php, mysql, import

Hi guys i am trying to display some items that i have on my database but i am having some problems.

```
        ...<div class="span9">
            <div class="row">
                <section id="projects">
                    <ul id="thumbs">
<?PHP 
require("_include/config.inc.php"); <- My database info
$db = "mydb"; <- database that i want to fetch the data
mysql_connect(SQL_HOST, SQL_USER, SQL_PASS) OR <- connect to the database from the config file
die("ERROR: Connection failed. ".mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db) OR
die("ERROR: Database already open. ".mysql_error());

$sql = "SELECT * FROM web_projects WHERE display>0;
$project = mysql_query($sql);

if(mysql_num_rows($qryProject)>0) {
  while($getProject = mysql_fetch_object($project)) {
    echo '<li class=\"item-thumbs span3 '.utf8_encode($getProject->category).'\">';
    echo '<a class=\"hover-wrap fancybox\" data-fancybox-group=\"gallery\" title=\"'.utf8_encode($getProject->title).'\" href=\"'.utf8_encode($getProject->image).'\">';
    echo '<span class=\"overlay-img\"></span>';
    echo '<span class=\"overlay-img-thumb font-icon-plus\"></span>';
    echo '</a>';        
    echo '<img src=\"'.utf8_encode($getProject->imageb).'\" alt=\"'.utf8_encode($getProject->desc).'\">';
    echo '</li>';
  }
}

?>
                </section>
```

Nothing shows.
i want to create like a post from my database without editing the html file.
What i did was create the index.php file and added this code to be able to edit from the database a create a new post from the database. But like i said nothing shows. no even a error.

Comment: You're missing the end quote on the `$sql = ` line. Is that in the real code, or just a copying error?

Comment: it was a  copy error

Comment: Can you fix the question so we can try to answer the actual problem?

Comment: Check your PHP error log to see if there are any errors being reported.

Comment: Comments should be marked with `//`, not `<-`. E.g. `// My database info`. Is that in your actual code, or just here? Please post real, working code, it's hard to help you if we can't tell what's real and what you added in SO.

Answer (score 1):

There`s missing " on this line

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM web_projects WHERE display>0;
```

But I am not sure if it will resolve your problem.

Comment: About 10 minutes after you posted this he commented that that was a copying error.